# SSTP Client with Search Domains

Tags: macos, network, vpn, dns

I am connecting to my work's vpn via [sstp-client](http://sstp-client.sourceforge.net/) on my mac.
Everything is working except that I cannot use short names in urls.

For example, if I type "servera" it doesn't resolve to anything. If I use "servera.work.domain" it will work fine.

When connected to the vpn, if I look at `etc/resolv/conf` I can see there are only the two nameservers and no `domain` listed. When disconnected, the search domains reappear in the file.

Here is the command used to invoke sstp from a script.

```
sudo sstpc --log-stderr --log-level 4 --cert-warn --user $UN --password $PW $SERVICE_URL usepeerdns require-mschap-v2 noauth noipdefault defaultroute refuse-eap noccp
```

I have also tried adding `domain work.domain` to the end of the command without luck.

Any ideas how to get this working?

Comment: Are you connecting the SSTP tunnel with the `usepeerdns` option? What happens if you turn that off/on?

Comment: I am. If I remove that setting, I am able to access "servera.work.domain" but I can no longer access things like "google.com". Also the resolv.conf becomes empty.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the `sstpc` command to have pppd call a script like so.

```
sudo sstpc --log-stderr --log-level 4 --cert-warn --user $UN --password $PW $SERVICE_URL call myScript
```

Then use the terminal to create the script. *I believe this file needs execute permissions but I"m not 100% sure on that...*

`sudo touch /etc/ppp/peers/myScript`

This script should contain all of the pppd options needed for the vpn connection. In my case I used this.

```
usepeerdns 
require-mschap-v2 
noauth 
noipdefault 
defaultroute 
refuse-eap 
noccp 
domain work.domain
```

The key is the last option `domain`. For some reason we are unable to add it via the command line, but by using this file we can set the proper search domain.